# Getting count of unique values in pandas Dataframe when there is a list object in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, instagram, data-analysis

So basically I am trying to analyse instagram accounts. I have scraped intagram using selenium and created a datafram which includes links to the post, number of likes and hashtags used. So in the data frame i have included list object in a cloumn and i awant to find the count of unique hashtags used in total.
This is how thw dataframe looks like.

```
                                      links  ...                                           hashtags
0  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLrU5s5g7L7/  ...  [#data, #datascience, #technology, #machinelea...
1  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLojnLQgEVs/  ...  [#datascience, #machinelearning, #python, #art...
2  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLjhzPxgpkM/  ...  [#python, #AI, #ML, #artificialintelligence, #...
3  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLgUsXAgOah/  ...  [#datascience, #machinelearning, #python, #art...
4  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLdfVBHAibb/  ...  [#billgates, #softwareengineering, #softwareen...
5  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLbGqrYgl74/  ...  [#python3, #python, #pythonprogramming, #AI, #...
6  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLZKOEcg72M/  ...  [#python3, #python, #pythonprogramming, #AI, #...
7  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLYe9AJgg0U/  ...  [#datascience, #machinelearning, #python, #art...
8  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLV4UP5Af-2/  ...  [#pawrihoraihai, #programming, #coding, #progr...
9  https://www.instagram.com/p/CLTSxc5g2cJ/  ...  [#datascience, #machinelearning, #python, #art..
```

I have stored hashtags as a list object corresponding to the respective post. Is there any better way to store hashtags? And how to get the count of unique hashtags used overall.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

arr = df['hashtags'].apply(pd.Series).values.ravel()  # Consolidate all hashtags
count_dict = Counter(arr)
```

Comment: I followed your method and i got counts of unique hashtags but i am getting most nan values. Why is that? Is it because of varied sizes of list?  ``` Counter({nan: 59, '#artificialintelligence': 10, '#machinelearning': 10, '#datascience': 9, ....```

Comment: Indeed. You can just drop this key, i.e. `del count_dict[np.nan]`.

Comment: yeahhh okayy!! one more question! Now it returns a counter object right? So I want to sort the counts in decreasing oreder and print top 5 hashtags used. So how do I do it?

Comment: You can essentially treat it as a `dict`, so something like `pd.Series(count_dict).nlargest(5)` would do it.